# python-redis:ConnectionError: Error 32 while writing to socket. Broken pipe?

Tags: python, redis

I want to test the value of redis can support up to 512MB
language:python

```
import redis
conn = redis.Redis()
temp_dict={}
for i in range(1000000):
    temp_dict.update({str(i):str(i)})
conn.hmset('hash-key',temp_dict)
```

errors:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
     in ()
    ----> 1 conn.hmset('hash-key',temp_dict)

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/client.pyc in hmset(self, name, mapping)
   2009         for pair in iteritems(mapping):
   2010             items.extend(pair)
-> 2011         return self.execute_command('HMSET', name, *items)
   2012 
   2013     def hmget(self, name, keys, *args):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/client.pyc in execute_command(self, *args, **options)
    671             if not connection.retry_on_timeout and isinstance(e, TimeoutError):
    672                 raise
--> 673             connection.send_command(*args)
    674             return self.parse_response(connection, command_name, **options)
    675         finally:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/connection.pyc in send_command(self, *args)
    608     def send_command(self, *args):
    609         "Pack and send a command to the Redis server"
--> 610         self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
    611 
    612     def can_read(self, timeout=0):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/connection.pyc in send_packed_command(self, command)
    601                 errmsg = e.args[1]
    602             raise ConnectionError("Error %s while writing to socket. %s." %
--> 603                                   (errno, errmsg))
    604         except:
    605             self.disconnect()

ConnectionError: Error 104 while writing to socket. Connection reset by peer.
```

Comment: Please add a complete error description to your question including the error traceback.

Comment: Has been completed, trouble you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the data inserted at one time is too large, and the data can be separated and only 100000 pieces can be hmset at a time。

```py
import redis
conn = redis.Redis()

for x in range(10): 
    temp_dict={}
    for i in range(100000):
        temp_dict.update({str(i):str(i)})
    conn.hmset('hash-key',temp_dict)
```

Comment: Yeah, batching will definitely help here.